# How do I install DropBear SSH on Android?

Tags: ssh

I would like to install DropBear SSH on my 64 bit Android 5.1 device, but it seems that all the installation tutorials and how-tos have disappeared or contain links to broken files/downloads.

Could someone please explain the proper way to accomplish this?

FURTHER DETAILS:

- This question comes from [this other](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24827/searching-for-root-mode-ssh-server-for-64-bit-android-v5-and-above): an attempt to install some SSH Server on a modern (September 2015 at least) Android device that has (nearly) failed with many tested apps. Command line installation of Dropbear is a different approach to the problem.

Comment: Note to potential close-voters: OP isn't asking for an app, but wants installation help. Sopalajo comes here on my suggestion, the "is there an app for X" part was/is already dealt with at SR. OP knows about where to find it – the question asked here is how to make it fly.

Comment: I hope it is all right now, @Izzy. The link is added, I have no trustworthy sources for the Dropbear code, and all I have tried are apps, not command-line methods.

Comment: The link is there (to SR), where I've left a link to the [busybox.net binaries download page](http://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.21.1/) (so you don't need to fiddle with an installer additionally). Doing that manually, you'd need to create all those symlinks to the main binary (at least those you want). What's available it tells you when calling it without any parameters. You should place the binary in `/system/xbin`, and create the symlinks in the same place. I just cannot tell you further for the "how to get sshd running" part.

Comment: @Izzy, do those versions of BusyBox include the Dropbear binaries?

Comment: I don't know, haven't tried them all. The x86_64 version has not (oops: [none has](http://www.busybox.net/tinyutils.html), sorry). What's your architecture? x86_64, mips64, …? One more pointer: [Some useful 64-bit (aarch64) binaries: busybox, dropbear](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-9/development/useful-64-bit-aarch64-binaries-busybox-t2931373) (XDA)

Comment: @Izzy: I feature a `amd64-v8a`. The Android version is too 64 bits, or so I believe. I don't think that `aarch64` binaries could work, but I am not deeply experienced on Android. I was thinking there was some sort of legacy-compatibility on modern CPUs; some sort of WoW (Windows on Windows) for running 32 bit programs on 64 bit Windows systems.

Comment: The bad part, @Izzy, is: maybe as for today (September 2015) the new 64 bit cores are too recent and will have compatibility issues with not-too-recent apps and low-level programs like `OpenSSH` and `Dropbear`.

Comment: I agree with the "early birds" case. This doesn't render your question here unanswerable though: As indicated, I could guide you through the installation part (be it `busybox` or a separate `dropbox` binary which I think is the case with that XDA post), which is quite easy – but I've never used that kind of (command-line) SSHD on Android, so I cannot guide you with that; someone else certainly can (someone must have done this already). This isn't arch dependent, so as soon as the binaries are available (SR-part of your Q), you're ready to go then.

Answer (score 6):

First as a side-note for other readers: We're not talking about "an app" here (those have already been tried and didn't work on that architecture), but about a command-line binary. *DropBear* sometimes is part of [Busybox](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_991), or it comes as [separate binary](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-9/development/useful-64-bit-aarch64-binaries-busybox-t2931373).

---

Now for the installation part. Binaries you install yourself best go to `/system/xbin`, which is in the `$PATH` but usually "initially empty" (Android's own stuff is in `/system/bin` and `/system/sbin`), so we run a very low risk of "collisions". So either `adb shell` or terminal to your device and make sure you're root. I further assume you've already transferred the `dropbear`/`busybox` binary to your SD card.

```
mount -o remount,rw /system        # make sure we can write to system
cp /sdcard/busybox /system/xbin    # copy the binaries to /system/xbin
cp /sdcard/dropbear /system/xbin
cd /system/xbin                    # switch to our target directory
chmod 755 busybox dropbear         # make sure we've set the correct permissions
busybox --install /system/xbin     # advice busybox to create all its symlinks here
```

Installation part done (skip the `dropbear` parts here if your `dropbear` comes with `busybox` – and vice versa, skip the `busybox` part if not needed.

Now, we need to make `dropbear` fly. I've never tried this myself, so I refer to [an external script at Github](https://github.com/dpavlin/android-command-line/blob/master/adb-install-dropbear.sh) for that. In short (and in case that link dies), again assuming the required files are already copied to your SD card:

```
# Creating a home-dir for DropBear
mkdir /data/dropbear
chmod 755 /data/dropbear
mkdir /data/dropbear/.ssh
chmod 700 /data/dropbear/.ssh
# Copy over our files
mv /sdcard/authorized_keys /data/dropbear/.ssh/
chown root: /data/dropbear/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 /data/dropbear/.ssh/authorized_keys
# Generate a hostkey, so we can use DropBear
dropbearkey -t rsa -f /data/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key
dropbearkey -t dss -f /data/dropbear/dropbear_dss_host_key
```

An additional part if you want *DropBear* to auto-start at boot:

```
cat << EOF >> /etc/init.local.rc

# start Dropbear (ssh server) service on boot
service sshd /system/xbin/dropbear -s
   user  root
   group root
   oneshot

EOF
```

Note that this assumes your device supports `init.d` scripts. First check for the availability of that file to make sure.

Finally, don't forget to make `/system` read-only again. Either reboot at this point (so you also can check that *DropBear* starts as intended), or at least execute

```
mount -o remount,ro /system
```

for now, postponing the reboot. To start the service manually, it should be possible executing that block via some shell script (so you could e.g. have a [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) task for starting and another one for stopping the daemon, and even make shortcuts to those tasks on your homescreen for manual control). Again, I have not tested this part, so it's "pure theory".

Good luck with DropBear and BusyBox!

Comment: So I understand that, after the installation procedure, the command line to start the SSH service should be `/system/xbin/dropbear -s` ? And I presume it could be run as root (via `su`) or normal user, of course.

Comment: I've tried this and it works. There's no ready `dropbear` binary (at least I haven't found one) so you have to config and make a source like this one: https://github.com/ubiquiti/dropbear-android (changing the version to a newer one doesn't seem to work so keep it at `2018.76` or you'll have to edit the patch)

Answer (score 5):

Install Termux ([Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en), *F-Droid*, *Fossdroid*)

```
apt update
apt ugpgrade
apt install dropbear
```

I personally chose OpenSSH toover Dropbear

```
apt install openssh
```

To run the server

```
sshd
```

Unless your device is rooted you won't be able to run `sshd` as root. Note that running as non-root implies that ports below 1024 cannot be bound to. In Termux any packages have been configured to have compatible default values - the ftpd, httpd, and sshd servers default to 8021, 8080 and 8022, respectively.

If you want to run `sshd` as root try this script:
https://gist.github.com/cycojesus/57409ffed9066ce7f4d4

At that point you will be able to bind `sshd` to port 22.

Comment: Link to GitHub is dead.

Comment: What would be and how can you set in this case the username and password to log in, SFTP, SCP... etc?